# Tkinter treeview child displays at the bottom

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, parent-child

I'm currently experiencing an issue where I'm calling treeview in one function and the child is being returned in another function upon double clicking on a selection, but the child is displaying at the very bottom of all selections instead of each individual parent. These are both in for loops, it works as in I'm receiving correct results back per selection, but it just displays under the very last parent.

I have tried indexing at 0, but it didn't make a difference. Appreciate any help.

First function:

```
count += 1
trv.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, values=[patients_id, patients_name1, access, study_uid, study_date, time, patdob])
```

Second function:
Double_click(event)

```
trv.insert(count, index='end', values=[seuid1, series_desc])
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm experiencing, anonymized samples.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you out. As it's currently written, it's hard to reproduce the problem; there's not enough code.

Comment: You should get the `iid` of the double-clicked item and use it instead of `count` in the double-clicked function.

Comment: @acw1668 it worked! Thank you so much, I've been at this non stop for over a week while working on other areas of this project. Please can you add your comment above as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks again.